# What is the "Task group" field in a SharePoint Task list for?

Tags: sharepoint

Could someone tell me how the field "Task Group" is used in standard SharePoint Task Lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it to be a "support" type column. It doesn't really get shown anywhere by default but it's filtered against during the usage of one type of view.

The naming convention they chose isn't very intuitive.  Basically when you assign a task to a user account this field is blank. But if you assign a task to a "group", i.e., an active directory security group, this field will get auto populated by SharePoint.

When a SharePoint visitor looks at the task list and chooses the 'my groups' view then this field would be evaluated, e.g., "is visitor a member of this group, if yes, display task".  HTH

Answer (score 1):

In your view markup, when you open it in SharePoint designer, add this to the `<Where>` tag

```
<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
<FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
</Membership>
```

and save and it will work perfectly